# Coins tossing probability based problem.

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

Question **Suppose we toss 8 coin simultaneously, then find probability of getting at least 6 heads.**

The bookish solution uses binomial probability formula,

**But I tried Solving it any other way, what I did, for finding favourable cases was**

**Total cases -  [ (0 H ) + (7 H)  +  (8 H)]**

(7H) = cases with exactly 7 heads.

(8H) = cases with exactly 8 heads.

(0H) = cases with no heads or all
tails.

**Now for probability, I can say,**

**1 - [P(0 H) + P (7 H)  +  P (8 H)]**

Also, we know,

P(0H) = 1/256

P(7H) = 8/256

P(8H) = 1/256

**Hence final answer comes**

**1 - (10/256) = 246/256.**

And **correct ans was 37/256.**

And I can't really understand why such huge difference with everything looking good?

Comment: Your work is correct.

Comment: Let $X$ be the number of heads. Then you're looking at $X=0,1,2,3,4,5$ for the failures and $X=6,7,8$. So that would render the probability as $$P(6)+P(7)+P(8)=1-P(0)-P(1)-P(2)-P(3)-P(4)-P(5),$$ not $1-(P(0)+P(7)+P(8)$.

Comment: How could the answer be $\frac {246}{256}$?  That's nearly $1$.  And why would you think that the probability of getting at least $6$ Heads is equal to $1$ minus the probabilities of getting $0,7,8$ Heads?

Comment: @Semiclassical Oh, yes, what I  took was the case of atmost 2 heads. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

Given $8$ coins are tossed simultanousely.

Total outcomes are: $2\underbrace{\times \dotsb \times} 2=2^8=256$.

Favorable outcomes are 6 heads +  7 heads + 8 heads. Therefore

$$C_{8,6}+C_{8,7}+C_{8,8}=28+8+1=37$$

Hence $$P(E)=\frac{\text{n°of favorable outcomes}}{\text{Total outcomes}}=\frac{37}{256}$$